# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql

Al escribir el siguiente procedimiento:

```
delimiter //
create function autor_nac(v_id int) returns NVARCHAR (50)
begin
declare Nombre_Nacionalidad NVARCHAR (50);
set Nombre_Nacionalidad = (select CONCAT (nombre,"  ",nacionalidad) from autor
where id=v_id);
returns  Nombre_Nacionalidad;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

Aparece el error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Nombre_Nacionalidad; end' at line 7

He intentado escribir tanto funciones y procedimientos, y al momento de correrlos aparece este error,

Agradezco todas las respuestas posibles, por su atención gracias.

Comment: al momento de es poner set @Nombre_Nacionalidad vuelve a marcar syntax error en el bloque

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: **Al final** es `return`, no `returns`... **`return  Nombre_Nacionalidad;`**

Comment: #1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: Tienes que agregar esto antes del `begin`: **`DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA`** Revisa [lo que dice el manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html) al respecto.

Comment: Ya se realizo, gracias por la respuesta, revisare el manual mas detenidamente

Comment: Me alegro. He escrito una respuesta, sobre todo para explicar el motivo del error `1418` aparecido posteriormente de modo que quede una constancia de cómo resolverlo en estos casos. Quizá sería bueno que edites la pregunta, poniendo que aparece también ese error y la pregunta/respuesta pueda servir a otros que se encuentren con un caso parecido al tuyo.

Answer (score -1):

Inicialmente había un error de sintaxis aquí:

<s>`returns  Nombre_Nacionalidad;`</s>

La forma correcta es:

`return  Nombre_Nacionalidad;`

En cuanto al error:

> `#1418` - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you might want
>   to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

aparecido una vez corregido el error de sintaxis, el mismo te indica que es debido a que tienes activado el modo `binary logging`.

El manual de referencia [explica en qué consiste](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html):

> El registro binario contiene información sobre sentencias de SQL que
>   modifican el contenido de la base de datos. Esta información se
>   almacena en forma de "eventos" que describen las modificaciones. El
>   registro binario tiene dos propósitos importantes:
>
> - Para la replicación, el registro binario se utiliza en los servidores maestros de replicación como un registro de las
>     declaraciones que se enviarán a los servidores esclavos. El servidor
>     maestro envía los eventos contenidos en su registro binario a sus
>     esclavos, que ejecutan esos eventos para realizar los mismos cambios
>     de datos que se realizaron en el maestro.
> - Ciertas operaciones de recuperación de datos requieren el uso del registro binario. Después de restaurar un archivo de copia de
>     seguridad, se vuelven a ejecutar los eventos en el registro binario
>     que se registraron después de que se realizó la copia de seguridad.
>     Estos eventos actualizan las bases de datos desde el punto de la copia
>     de seguridad.

Teniendo en cuenta eso, el manual también indica que puedes poner a tu consulta lo siguiente:

```
DETERMINISTIC 
READS SQL DATA
```

De ese modo indicas que esta función es determinista (y no modifica los datos), por lo que es segura.

El código quedaría entonces así:

```
delimiter //
create function autor_nac(v_id int) returns NVARCHAR (50)
DETERMINISTIC 
READS SQL DATA
begin
declare Nombre_Nacionalidad NVARCHAR (50);
set Nombre_Nacionalidad = (select CONCAT (nombre,"  ",nacionalidad) from autor
where id=v_id);
return  Nombre_Nacionalidad;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```